# is it possible to completely disable spamassassin using spamassassin user_prefs

Tags: email, spamassassin

I am loading spamassassin user_prefs using `user_scores_*` sql-functions.

There are many users in my system who don't want to use spamassassin at all. Is there an option to do so?

I know I could set the `required_score` to something really high, but the scanning would be an unnecessary waste of resources then

Comment: depends on how you call spamassassin. usually you have some type of "glue" between the mailserver and spamassassin. configure this glue to skip SA for these users.

Comment: Well, spamassassin is being invoked by postfix using the `content_filter` option. I would need to create an extra wrapper between postfix and spamassassin. However, as spamassassin fetches the user preferences from the database anyway, to have spamassassin directly decide whether it should scan or not.

Comment: I am not really sure why anyone would mark this question as off topic or non-constructive. Please atleast leave a reason if you do so. I am ofcourse willing to improve my question if it's not good enough.

Comment: @Zulakis any reason why my answer wouldn't be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use this short circuit:

> **whitelist_to** add@ress.com
>   If the given address appears as a recipient
>   in the message headers (Resent-To, To, Cc, obvious envelope recipient,
>   etc.) the mail will be whitelisted. *Useful if you're deploying
>
>   SpamAssassin system-wide, and don't want some users to have their mail
>
>   filtered.* Same format as whitelist_from. There are three levels of
>   To-whitelisting, whitelist_to, more_spam_to and all_spam_to. Users in
>   the first level may still get some spammish mails blocked, but users
>   in all_spam_to should never get mail blocked.
>
> The headers checked for whitelist addresses are as follows: if
>   Resent-To or Resent-Cc are set, use those; otherwise check all
>   addresses taken from the following set of headers:
>
> ```
>     To
>     Cc
>     Apparently-To
>     Delivered-To
>     Envelope-Recipients
>     Apparently-Resent-To
>     X-Envelope-To
>     Envelope-To
>     X-Delivered-To
>     X-Original-To
>     X-Rcpt-To
>     X-Real-To
> ```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. The reason I am struggling with this is that most of the mentioned headers can be faked quite easily. As spamassassin is invoked with the username of the recipient anyway (as necessary for user based settings. this is even with aliases expanded already), it should probably use this one and not some maybe bogus headers.

Comment: Also, if sending mail to multiple recipients, the mail is not being filtered if only one single whitelisted person is in `To` or `Cc`. This is far from what I am looking for. As I already said before, spamassassin must be invoked with the `-u` argument anyway which specifies exactly one final recipient. This is what should be used for this setting.

Comment: You realize that mail to multiple recipients is actually multiple mails, and treated as so by any MTA?

Comment: Anyhow, you should really just install `amavisd-new` and set up SQL user preferences, in that manner the mail will actually be sent to spamassassin or not, not sent to spamassassin to not be scanned.

Comment: Of course mails with multiple recipients (aka RCPT TO) get treated as multiple mails by MTAs, atleast when configured to so (in postfix: `transport_destination_recipient_limit = 1`). The option `whitelist_to` is however NOT only checking the `RCPT TO` envelope, but also various other headers (listed above), which can be set to anything by a potential spammer.  I want to do exactly what you described, use the SQL user preferences (which already exist for spamassassin!) to decide whether mail should be scanned by SA or not. My question was about doing this with spamassassin, not by introducing..

Comment: ..another layer of complexity, like amavis. But I already explained all this in my previous comments...

Comment: Well, the only other option I can think of would be to remove spamassassin from the content scan in postfix, and have your LDA call it directly. The reason I suggest amavisd is because it is a fairly well understood piece of code between the MTA and spamasssassin. Otherwise you're going to have to write it yourself.

Comment: Basically, there is no option to call spamassassin, then tell it not to scan. The option is to call or not call spamassassin. Maybe you could set up a local transport in postfix which you could call for the users who don't want scanning. Do you use SQL backed users in postfix?

Comment: Yeah. I suppose you mean to use `transport_maps` and have a 'non-filtering' transport with `-o content_filter=` or what's your idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be able to specify a second virtual transport, the only question is how you'd override it on a per user basis..  it should be possible via SQL lookups, I honestly don't remember if there was a field in the userdb though.